# Text not breaking nicely in multicol environment

Tags: multicol

When I put text into the command below, it either tries to avoid breaking over a column (leaving a lot of white space), or (as in the picture below) breaks without the columns balancing. Is there a way to make the text within this command break more *regularly* and *evenly* when in multicol enviroment?

Smaller texts in this command are usually prone to the white space problem. Longer texts, like the picture, generally have to break and do so awkwardly.

Any ideas?

```
\newcommand{\prayertext}[1]{\medskip#1\par}%
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks to me like the right column is fine but the left column needs glue.  OTOH, you might be able to "balance" the columns by removing the glue from `\medskipamount`.  (`\setlength{\medskipamount}{6pt}`)